# syslog - log line classifications

Tags: saas, syslog, rsyslog

A very generic question; in the context of a programmer, with operational aspect of the process (program) in mind.

Is there any sort of best-practice / guide to classify messages, particularly in the context of SaaS / multi-tenancy (server) software environment, which would be generating errors and warnings due to user actions or misconfiguration. Due to the nature of the software, most modules that I am having to deal with, are stateless; i.e when an error happens due to user-error, it is quite hard to distinguish between that and an operational error (like network misconfiguration, etc).

What I want to know is from some of you experienced folks; what is the sensible logic to be employed here, in order to make it easy for the operations boys/girls to classify these messages, and identify problems?

Comment: Cross posting is not allowed on the stack exchange network: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/85514 Maybe you should remove one of your questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just three aspects from an admin and log analysis/classification perspective:

- Make the tag field/program name configurable. Then one can configure multiple instances to use log tags like `app/user_1`, `app/user_2` etc., allowing for fast and simple filters on the syslog level.
- Structure you messages from left to right, so one can filter different categories of log lines with simple search patterns or regular expression. E.g. `config error - cannot parse line 123` or `runtime warning - lost connection to DB xyz`
- For very structured logs you might also take a look at the ['structured data' field in syslog-protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.3). So far it is rarely used and without tool support, but it allows for application log messages with namespaces and very clear key-value-attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers; especially structured-data; any idea how to pass that data via the [syslog()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) function

Comment: Just include it into the message field like with `syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "%s", "[exampleSDID@32473 ...] possibly followed by free text message")` -- AFAIK only NetBSD has a library function [syslogp(3)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?syslogp++NetBSD-current) for syslog-protocol, but that's very experimental and not available anywhere else (i.e. not usable in production).

Answer (score 0):

- Identify the servers and server types (name, ip address, etc.)
- Classify by severity, make sure all the clocks are in synch in order 
  to have the message ordered correctly.
- Put a message/error code to filter/create some rules in your monitoring tool.
- Put a module (used if several modules on one server)
- Put a category for addressing general services like networking, etc.

I guess you will gather the logs from the different machines with their syslog deamon to a central machine in charge of supervision/monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Most *nix processes log to syslog (or should at least) using a semi-standard format "Month Day 24H-Time host process_name[pid]: message". Syslog incorporates ways to indicate the message's severity, use them (though keep in mind that the severity is from the system's prospective, not the applications).

If message is a debugging problem then it's usually "Function_Name File_Name Line_No Error_Code Error_Desc"; otherwise the format of the message is entirely program dependent.

For multi-tenant systems it's pretty common for the "message" part to start with some form of tenant identification, followed by the actual log message.